# RSpec/Mongoid inheritance of defaults completely different result in test/development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, rspec, mongoid

This is one of those ones that makes you think you're going insane...

I have a class Section, and a DraftSection that inherits from it:

*(Trimmed for brevity)*

```
class Section
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :site

  field :name, type: String
end
```

And

```
class DraftSection < Section
  field :name, type: String, default: "New Section"
end
```

All simple stuff... console proves *(again, trimmed for brevity)*:

```
004 > site = Site.first
 => #<Site _id: initech, name: "INITECH"> 
005 > site.sections.build
 => #<Section _id: 1, site_id: "initech", name: nil> 
006 > site.draft_sections.build
 => #<DraftSection _id: 2, site_id: "initech", name: "New Section">
```

As you can see - the draft section name correctly defaults to "New Section" as it is overridden in the subclass.

Now when I run this spec:

```
describe "#new" do
  it "should return a draft section" do
    get 'new', site_id: site.id, format: :json
    assigns(:section).should == "Something..."
  end
end
```

Which tests this controller method:

```
def new
  @section = @site.draft_sections.build
  respond_with @section
end
```

Which fails (as expected), but with this:

```
Failure/Error: assigns(:section).should == "Something..."
   expected: "Something..."
        got: #<DraftSection _id: 1, site_id: "site-name-4", name: nil> (using ==)
```

What gives???

Update:

I figured it might be an issue with the different environment settings, so I looked at the mongoid.yml config file and saw this in the options:

```
# Preload all models in development, needed when models use
# inheritance. (default: false)
preload_models: true
```

I added it to the test environment settings too, but still no joy :(

Update 2 - the plot thickens...

Thought I'd try loading up the console in the test environment and trying the same as before:

```
001 > site = Site.first
 => #<Site _id: initech, name: "INITECH"> 
002 > site.draft_sections.build
 => #<DraftSection _id: 1, site_id: "initech", name: "New Section">
```

WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, no one's listening, but I'll post the solution here for future reference anyway...

For some reason, some time ago I had a debug session that meant I had left this code in my Spork.each_run block

```
  # Reload all model files when run each spec
  # otherwise there might be out-of-date testing
  # require 'rspec/rails'
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/controllers//*.rb"].each do |controller|
    load controller
  end
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models//*.rb"].each do |model|
    load model
  end
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib//*.rb"].each do |klass|
    load klass
  end
```

This was causing the models to get reloaded on each run of a spec. Not surprisingly, this screwed up the way the classes were set up in memory whilst the specs were running.

Definitely explains why it was such a hard one to debug...

So for future googlers with similar inheritance problems in Rspec only - make sure that there's nothing reloading models anywhere in the test stack.